# errors with android...says no attribute

Tags: android, attributes, indexing

I am trying to decode these errors.

It comes up when I view my app in different screens.

here is the download to an error log.

[Error Log Click Here](http://www.mediafire.com/?u99n13k60yd6ro9)

Comment: A half-meg of log, that we have to download and open? Not cool.

Comment: sorry...im not sure what one would need to understnad this

Comment: Hope you be more specific next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Highlight your project in the project view. Hit the `F5` (Refresh) key.
- Finish your XML file; `!MESSAGE sports.xml: Dimension "30" in attribute "textSize" is missing unit!`
- `!MESSAGE sports.xml: "30sp" in attribute "textStyle" is not a valid value`
- etc.

Start there.

Don't make anybody download a half-meg of Eclipse logs.

Comment: sorry...im new to this. i didnt know what was important

Comment: @bluejamesbond Now you know ;) There are easier ways to get error information, too. Also, when there are a lot of errors of one particular type, like your missing/incomplete attribute values, it's enough to just discuss a few examples.

Comment: im still confused. i dont know what the error is though...i would really appreciate it if you can explain on what is going on in the error. i pressed teh F5...it just refreshed everything

it comes with this error:
Index: 0, Size: 0
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log

Comment: @bluejamesbond Sounds like your Eclipse is messed up.

Comment: so i guess i have to redownload... :(
thank you dave for your help :D

Comment: @bluejamesbond No, you can try creating a new project after blowing away your metadata directory, or copy only your project files to a new directory, or...

Comment: still this error
Index: 0, Size: 0
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log

when i choose screensize WVGA

Comment: @bluejamesbond No clue. Could be an ADK issue, something in your project, no idea.

Comment: i guess..i can skip coding those screensizes

Comment: can u please look at my project...i can let u connect to my computer. that would be really helpful.

Comment: @bluejamesbond If you put it on github I may be able to take a look tomorrow, although I don't use Eclipse very much anymore.

Answer (score 7):

try putting "30.0sp" instead of "30" or "30sp". Dimension attributes are floating numbers and need a decimal point.

Worked for me.

Comment: I did that but did only help when I restarted android studio!